# Externally installing libraries, not only referring

Tags: r, roxygen2

I want to build a package which refers to other packages. To create referent to another package I simply create new .R file with my package name (let's say it's megapackage). I use in that file code following.

```
#' megapackage
#'
#' @docType package
#' @name megapackage
#' @import ggplot2
#' @import dplyr
#' @import zoo
#' @import gridExtra
#' @import scales
#' @import cowplot
#' @import TTR
NULL
```

Now the problem occurs when I do not have previously installed package (I get error `ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'megapackage'`). I mean, `@import` command works as a referent to library, but it will not install that package by default. How can I make it in such way that it will also install necessary packages, and not only refer to them in library ?

Comment: How do your users install your package?

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest reading Hadley's book *R Packages*. It's available free online. Here's [the relevant part](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#dependencies):

> Imports: packages listed here must be present for your package to
> work. In fact, any time your package is installed, those packages
> will, if not already present, be installed on your computer
> (devtools::load_all() also checks that the packages are installed).

Try running load_all() or installing your package in a clean installation of R.

Comment: That's pretty strange. It's suggest that it should be installed by default, while I cannot even build my package due to that error mention in my question. This error is omitted when I just install lacking packages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually install the package (not build it).

You need to have a `@import dplyr` in the .R file and `Imports: dplyr` in the DESCRIPTION file.

When you install the package with `install.packages("filepath", dependencies = T)` it should work then.

So you first have to have the external packages installed and build your package to get a `.tar.gz` file

You can use this .tar.gz package file now to install your package (with install.packages as outlined above). This should now also automatically install the external packages (when not already present).